# How to test best_in_place with rspec and capybara

Tags: rspec, best-in-place

The best_in_place gem is used for in place editing. It works in development application, but when tested with rspec and capybara, the tests are sometimes passed and sometimes failed. I am using best_in_place text_area with 'Save' and 'Cancel' buttons. The spec written is as follows.

```
    bip_area product, :description, "A new description" 
    click_button "Save"
    page.should have_content "A new description"
```

Sometimes the 'Save' button is also not recognized in rspec. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `click_button "Save"` is necessary even if your field has save and cancel buttons. So what's happening is `bip_area` is changing the input field *and telling the server* even before you say `click_button "Save"`. Therefore you have a race condition, where sometimes the Javascript run by `bip_area` finishes first, removing the Save button, and sometimes the `click_button` finishes first, doing a (noop) click.